# Bertbaseuncased install with spacy is not working

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, huggingface-transformers, spacy-transformers

I am trying to start an NLP project using spacy transformers. When trying to install bertbaseuncased I'm getting this error:

```
✘ No compatible package found for 'en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg' (spaCy
v3.6.0)
```

I've been researching for quite some time and haven't found anything to solve my issue. Here is what I'm running in the command line:

```
> pip install spacy-transformers
> python -m spacy download en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg
```

as per https://explosion.ai/blog/spacy-transformers

the spacy-transformers installation works just fine. I also tried different packages and they gave me similar errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in [a discussion on the Spacy github repo](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8243).

The explanation of the error is that `en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg`  is a Spacy 2.x model and you are using 3.x.

Instead of said model, you can download and use `en_core_web_trf`, which contains transformer models for Spacy 3.x:

```
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```